# SQL2005 reporting server: intense security activity

Tags: sql-server-2005

On my reporting server the Security log shows large numbers of Logon/Logoff events, often 10 or more, when you run pretty much any report in the Report Manager. Is this normal or is it a classic sign of having the wrong setup?

Some system details:

- Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2, virtual server running under VMWare).
- SQL Server 2005 SP3 Standard Edition, running databases, Report Manager, and Ananlysis Services cubes.
- No other major services on the machine (i.e. it's not a domain controller, Exchange server or anything like that).

Any ideas, please, guys?

Answer (score 0):

"I/O Write Bytes" doesn't necessarily mean *disk* I/O. This number includes file, network, and and device I/O (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938567.aspx).

I'd consider running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) against it, though you might not get anything helpful back.

You're not seeing anything odd in any of the event logs, right?

Comment: Ah, not just disk I/O. Thanks, Evan, I didn't realise that. The Security log does indeed show a lot of Logon/Logoff events. I've beefed up the question accordingly.